# using the result of a program called from Perl

Tags: perl

I want to use and manipulate the result of a program I call from Perl:

`system (zgrep "failed at" $in_fname);`

I want to take the lines made by `zgrep` manipulate them and then write the manipulated lines to a new file.
how do I do it?

Comment: *`zgrep` is a `grep` command working on zipped files.

Comment: In that code, `zgrep` is a bareword. What *exact* code are you using to execute zgrep?

Comment: @Ether, `zgrep` is a Linux command:                http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm

Comment: @Ilya: I understand that zgrep is a command :p My point is the code you included in your question *is not valid Perl syntax*.

Comment: @Ether, I don't know why you're saying it. I ran the program and it worked very well. What it does is it prints to the screen the result all the lines in the file that contain the phrase "failed at".
Obviously that `$in_fname` is defined before, I didn't write that line because I think that it's obvious that I define all my variables. 

You put doubt in my heart so I tried it now on a windows machine (I have don't have a Linux machine at home) with `system (dir);` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`system` does not return the results but the external program *exit status*.

You must capture the result with the ` operator (backquote):

```
my $var = `zgrep "failed at" $in_fname`;
```

Comment: There's only about 4 pixels difference between a single quote that slants this way: ' and a single quote that slants that way: ` . So I never use actual backtick characters, they are bad for maintenance. I would write that as: my $var = qx/zgrep "failed at" $in_fname/;

Comment: Since I needed the separate lines, I used `my @var = \`zgrep ...\`;` and each entry at `@var` was one result line.

Comment: @tadmc: +1 for your comment, but I use `qx{}` since the shape of the characters is visually "enclosing".

Answer (score 5):

You can also use Perl's open statement. Just add a pipe (|) at the end. See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open()-for-IPC

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $zgreph, 'zgrep "failed at" $in_fname |'
        or die "can't fork: $!";

while (my $data = <$zgreph>) {
        print $data;
}
close $zgreph
        or die "error closing: $! $?";
```

This might be a better approach, because you get the data as it comes, rather than all at once. At least if you set the predefined variable $| (autoflush). See http://www.ira.cnr.it/manuals/perl/manual/pod/perlvar.html for predefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

**OP:**  "I want to use and manipulate the result of a system call"

No, you don't.

You want to run a program and capture the results.

A [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is something entirely different.

As *tchrist* so ably pointed out, [`syscall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syscall.html) is the perl function to use to access system calls.